# count the number of variables, group it and sum in r

Tags: r

I want to count the number of different variables in the column by its types and do the sum of like variables length in another column. the data looks like

```
LEGEND  LENGTH  PCI
Existing Bike Path  14991   NO
Existing Bike Path  1116    NO
Planned Bike Route  9387    Yes
Planned Bike Route  4656    Yes
Planned Bike Route  4186    Yes
Planned Bike Route  4186    Yes
Planned Bike Route  4186    Yes
Planned Bike Route  4186    Yes
Existing Bike Path  5000    Yes
```

I want the output be like

```
Legend  count   sum of length
Existing Bike Path  3   21107
Planned Bike Route  6   30787
```

i was able to count the number of variables but did not know how to add the length and make another column.

```
library(plyr)
library(foreign)
a1=read.dbf("OBJECTID_1.dbf",as.is=FALSE)
z1= t(  count(a1    ,"  a1$LEGEND   ")  )
write.csv   (   z1, file=   "   object1 .csv"   )
```

Please help !!!
Lira

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
aggregate(LENGTH ~ LEGEND, data, function(x) {c(no=length(x), sum = sum(x))})

#              LEGEND LENGTH.no LENGTH.sum
#1 Existing_Bike_Path         3      21107
#2 Planned_Bike_Route         6      30787
```

For some reason if you want to use `plyr` then here is an option

```
library(plyr)
ddply(data, .(LEGEND), summarize, no = length(LENGTH), sum = sum(LENGTH))

#              LEGEND no   sum
#1 Existing_Bike_Path  3 21107
#2 Planned_Bike_Route  6 30787
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the dplyr package...

```
library(dplyr)

# make your data frame
legend <- c('Existing Bike Path','Existing Bike Path', 'Planned Bike Route', 'Planned Bike Route','Planned Bike Route', 'Planned Bike Route', 'Planned Bike Route','Planned Bike Route', 'Existing Bike Path')
length <- c(14991, 1116, 9387, 4656, 4186, 4186, 4186, 4186, 5000)
pci <- c('NO', 'NO', 'YES' , 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES', 'YES')
data <- data.frame(legend, length, pci)

# funnel data through group_by and summarize to get the desired count and sum
data %>% group_by(legend) %>% summarize(count = n(), sum_o_length=sum(length))
```

Your output looks like this...

```
              legend     count     sum_o_length
              (fctr)     (int)            (dbl)
1 Existing Bike Path        3            21107
2 Planned Bike Route        6            30787
```

In order to write to csv...

```
# store output as data frame
output <- data %>% group_by(legend) %>% summarize(count = n(), sum_of_length=sum(len))
write.table(output, file='output.csv', sep=',', row.names = FALSE)
```